# Maximising a sum with respect to the unit ball.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that I have a vector $\boldsymbol{v} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, for some dimension $d>1$, and suppose I want to consider the sum

$$
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{d}v_k\right)^2.
\end{align*}
$$

Is there any way to find the maximum of this sum with the restriction that $\|\boldsymbol{v}\|_2 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^{d}v_k^2\right)^{1/2} =1$? I mean for starters, if $\|\boldsymbol v\|_2 =1$, then for each component of $\boldsymbol{v}$, we must have that $|v_k| \leq 1$ otherwise the constraint isn't satisfied. However, I am having difficulty finding an upper bound to the displayed sum. I understand that the natural upper bound would be to say something like $d$, by using Cauchy's Inequality, but is there any other sharper upper bound that does not depend on the dimension?

Answer (score 1):

[Cauchy's inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchysInequality.html) gives $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{d}v_k\right)^2 \leq d (\sum_{k=1}^{d}v_k^2) = d$.

The maximum is reached when all $v_k$'s are equal, i.e. $v_k = \sqrt\frac{1}{d}$